# Android Sqlite Storage Limit

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application, which takes user location in every 30 seconds and storing in the application's own sqlite db. In my calculation I need to store around 1 Lac records. I have only 1 table with following details,
ID(Integer), latitude(real), longitude(real), date(text), time(text).

Is it safe to store the details in sqlite?

Will it cause any problem in regards to performance.

Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

SQLite's limits are usually not of interest on mobile devices. The device is by far more constrained.

For example if you add 1kB of data each 30 seconds you'll generate around 60GB of data per year. That's not going to fit on any device but would be no problem for SQLite.

Performance can be a problem if your queries are slow. Indexed queries run in some variation of `log(N)` time which means that working with billions of row of data has roughly the same performance as a few thousand. If your queries are complex you can easily get into N^2 complexity or worse meaning that performance will be terrible once you reach like a thousand rows. A bit more here: http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html

I would recommend to keep that size limit in mind and add a way to recycle data if there is not enough space. The internal storage (not enough space to install new apps?) is typically very limited.

Comment: So can you please tell me the size of my one record. I have specified the field details in question.

Comment: I don't know how large one is exactly. But you can find out yourself if you create an example database and fill it with some records, then add a few thousand and see how the file size changes. You'll get the most accurate result if you generate pseudo random data that matches actual in-production use. I suspect 1 record is around 150 byte so you can store quite a lot in a few megabytes. (~ 10x more than if one record is 1kB but if your app was running for 1 year that would still amount to 6GB which is beyond phone capacity)

Comment: The application is only for special purpose of 5-6 months usage. One day app will be active up to 4-5 hours(inserting record in every 30 second). So saving data in sqlite does make any sense ?.

Comment: If you want to store data on the device yes, SQLite is probably the best way. Every other way of storing data has at least the same size problem. It's nothing you can change unless you store all data in the cloud or change the approach in other ways. An actual database (like SQLite) is made for storing data in huge quantities and it has many benefits over simple text files, shared preferences, .. since it guarantees thread safety, reproducible performance, memory management (you can't load a 200MB text file into RAM, but you can easily use a 200MB SQLite database) etc.

Answer (score 3):

I have also worked on a similar kind of an application where i used to store user's location every second. The records count used to exceed way beyond Lacs.
I was also afraid about the database errors or any such performance issues too, but, surprisingly, till date, no such issues have come forward.

I also, implemented a method to backup my database whenever the records count reached 1 billion, and refresh the database as a brand new.

To achieve this, i created another table that contains the unique ID and Timestamp of the backup database, along with its stored location on the device.

I also kept syncing every 1000 records to the webserver as a fail proof and the backup databases.

Interestingly, all this data was always in some KBs. :-)

Answer (score 2):

For your question you should read this,

http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html and

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteFullException.html

and also if you are asking about it's size then i think it's 2GB, so i don't think there is any problem if you store 1 lac records or more then that, also you can try

```
long getMaximumSize()
```

to check what is the maximum size.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option like this:

use this link for your help

http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html