# Send SQL data from one Android app to another Android app locally

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to make an Android App which will probably run on Chromebox or a powerful tablet. I want to use another app on about 10 more android phones to take orders and store order in SQLlite database of Chromebox or Tablet. 
These 10 phones will send orders to be stored in that local tablet/Chromebox connected with local WiFi.

They will also view reports from the data stored in that tablet or Chromebox. The premises will not have any internet connection. So all data needs to be stored and saved in Chromebox or powerful tablet.

Also we are talking of multiple orders during any given time. Is this plan feasible?

Comment: the [M Tiny series](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre/m-series-tiny/c/M-Series-Tiny) might be rather suitable for a backend; just compare the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have never used Chromebox, I think as a tablet. If it is a local wifi, I think that it can be realized by fixing the IP of each terminal and exchanging data by [socket connection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket). Act Chromebox or tablet as server and phone as client.

You can also select SSLSocketConnection if you want to make a secure connection. I think data will be a serialized data class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would the data stored in SQL lite of tablet. Also is there any limit on the amount of data that can be stored in tablet using this way?

Comment: The limitation of SQLite is not an issue and limitation of tablet storage capacity may be a problem. It may be necessary to simulate how long it can be operated by measuring the data capacity per day. It seems that if it is general text data, it does not seem to be a problem so much, but if you include images etc., you may need regular backups. Other limitations on [SQLite's limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985022/android-sqlite-storage-limit) and [default socket connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981957/java-serversocket-connection-limit).